# How to replace ç (c cedilla) with English (US, international with dead keys) keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I freshly installed ElementaryOS, I speak French, have a QWERTY keyboard so I use English (US, international with dead keys) keyboard (useful to do "é" for exemple)

And it's supposed to do a "ç" when I press ' and then "c"

But it does "ć" (which is sadly useless in French)

Is there a way to edit that myself? Or is it an error in ElementaryOS?

Thank's for help !

Comment: Why don't you use the French keyboard? You can still have the rest in English but it will detect your keyboard correctly.

Comment: My laptop is a Xiaomi Mi Notebook air with a QWERTY keyboard (French keyboards are AZERTY) and I choosed to use QWERTY when I bought it. But I still speak french so I still need this c

Comment: Is this the keyboard? https://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_processed_/csm_MiAirOpen_c349e154c6.jpg

Comment: Did you try pressing Alt Gr + any other key? In my keyboard it gives lots of symbols, maybe there's the one you need as well. for example @ł€¶ŧ←↓→øþæßðđŋħł

Comment: Indeed there's a lot of symbols but not the one i'm looking for (and yes, this is my pc Sebastian)

Answer (score 1):

Install Character Map from AppCenter and then insert the special character with `Ctrl+Shift+u+unicode number of the character+Enter`, the unicode number that you get from the Character Map. For ç it's `Ctrl+Shift+u+00e7`.

Comment: Hm my question wasn't clear. In fact I need to replace this "ć" with "ç" when I press keys, as it's supposed to be. (Sorry for that mistake)